How do I perform an unstructured grid transition?
Firstly, I have a large existing grid and a small existing grid. I need to perform an unstructured transition between these two grids.

To do this, I figured out GMSH a little bit.
Secondly, who worked with GMSH, please tell me if it is possible to perform the meshing the model in the screenshot below completely in GMSH?

I have a lot of points with coordinates (x, y, z). I need to create a grid by points. How can this be done? When splitting the grid, it is not possible to control the size using the "Element size factor" or "Minimum/maximum element size" parameter. In the future, it will be necessary to build a second grid higher, only finer, and connect them in 3d.


script for GMSH
// Gmsh project created on Mon Jun 03 19:43:02 2024
SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");
Point(1) = {143.57, 111.1347315991, -28.85517391567};
Point(2) = {143.57, 111.0863688623, -24.59240963891};
Point(3) = {143.57, 111.1202830363, -20.32937265135};
Point(4) = {143.57, 111.2364258104, -16.06916792827};
Point(5) = {146.78, 111.1347315991, -28.85517391567};
Point(6) = {146.78, 111.0863688623, -24.59240963891};
Point(7) = {146.78, 111.1202830363, -20.32937265135};
Point(8) = {146.78, 111.2364258104, -16.06916792827};
Point(9) = {149.99, 111.1347315991, -28.85517391567};
Point(10) = {149.99, 111.0863688623, -24.59240963891};
Point(11) = {149.99, 111.1202830363, -20.32937265135};
Point(12) = {149.99, 111.2364258104, -16.06916792827};
Point(13) = {153.2, 111.1347315991, -28.85517391567};
Point(14) = {153.2, 111.0863688623, -24.59240963891};
Point(15) = {153.2, 111.1202830363, -20.32937265135};
Point(16) = {153.2, 111.2364258104, -16.06916792827};
Point(17) = {156.41, 111.1347315991, -28.85517391567};
Point(18) = {156.41, 111.0863688623, -24.59240963891};
Point(19) = {156.41, 111.1202830363, -20.32937265135};
Point(20) = {156.41, 111.2364258104, -16.06916792827};
Point(21) = {159.62, 111.1347315991, -28.85517391567};
Point(22) = {159.62, 111.0863688623, -24.59240963891};
Point(23) = {159.62, 111.1202830363, -20.32937265135};
Point(24) = {159.62, 111.2364258104, -16.06916792827};
Point(25) = {162.83, 111.1347315991, -28.85517391567};
Point(26) = {162.83, 111.0863688623, -24.59240963891};
Point(27) = {162.83, 111.1202830363, -20.32937265135};
Point(28) = {162.83, 111.2364258104, -16.06916792827};
Point(29) = {166.04, 111.1347315991, -28.85517391567};
Point(30) = {166.04, 111.0863688623, -24.59240963891};
Point(31) = {166.04, 111.1202830363, -20.32937265135};
Point(32) = {166.04, 111.2364258104, -16.06916792827};
Point(33) = {169.25, 111.1347315991, -28.85517391567};
Point(34) = {169.25, 111.0863688623, -24.59240963891};
Point(35) = {169.25, 111.1202830363, -20.32937265135};
Point(36) = {169.25, 111.2364258104, -16.06916792827};
Point(37) = {172.46, 111.1347315991, -28.85517391567};
Point(38) = {172.46, 111.0863688623, -24.59240963891};
Point(39) = {172.46, 111.1202830363, -20.32937265135};
Point(40) = {172.46, 111.2364258104, -16.06916792827};
Point(41) = {175.67, 111.1347315991, -28.85517391567};
Point(42) = {175.67, 111.0863688623, -24.59240963891};
Point(43) = {175.67, 111.1202830363, -20.32937265135};
Point(44) = {175.67, 111.2364258104, -16.06916792827};
Point(147) = {143.57, 112.0063668288, -11.81189049095};
Point(148) = {143.57, 112.8580886594, -7.563638747806};
Point(149) = {143.57, 113.7911924628, -3.327492330721};
Point(150) = {143.57, 114.8051634714, 0.8934863723831};
Point(151) = {143.57, 115.9752992759, 5.373959934968};
Point(152) = {143.57, 116.5470343647, 8.960299187787};
Point(153) = {146.78, 112.0063668288, -11.81189049095};
Point(154) = {146.78, 112.8580886594, -7.563638747806};
Point(155) = {146.78, 113.7911924628, -3.327492330721};
Point(156) = {146.78, 114.8051634714, 0.8934863723831};
Point(157) = {146.78, 115.9752992759, 5.373959934968};
Point(158) = {146.78, 116.5470343647, 8.960299187787};
Point(159) = {149.99, 112.0063668288, -11.81189049095};
Point(160) = {149.99, 112.8580886594, -7.563638747806};
Point(161) = {149.99, 113.7911924629, -3.327492330721};
Point(162) = {149.99, 114.8051634714, 0.8934863723831};
Point(163) = {149.99, 115.9752992759, 5.373959934968};
Point(164) = {149.99, 116.5470343647, 8.960299187787};
Point(165) = {153.2, 112.0063668288, -11.81189049095};
Point(166) = {153.2, 112.8580886594, -7.563638747806};
Point(167) = {153.2, 113.7911924628, -3.327492330721};
Point(168) = {153.2, 114.8051634714, 0.8934863723831};
Point(169) = {153.2, 115.9752992759, 5.373959934968};
Point(170) = {153.2, 116.5470343647, 8.960299187787};
Point(171) = {156.41, 112.0063668288, -11.81189049095};
Point(172) = {156.41, 112.8580886594, -7.563638747806};
Point(173) = {156.41, 113.7911924628, -3.327492330721};
Point(174) = {156.41, 114.8051634714, 0.8934863723831};
Point(175) = {156.41, 115.9752992759, 5.373959934968};
Point(176) = {156.41, 116.5470343647, 8.960299187787};
Point(177) = {159.62, 112.0063668288, -11.81189049095};
Point(178) = {159.62, 112.8580886594, -7.563638747806};
Point(179) = {159.62, 113.7911924628, -3.327492330721};
Point(180) = {159.62, 114.8051634714, 0.8934863723831};
Point(181) = {159.62, 115.9752992759, 5.373959934968};
Point(182) = {159.62, 116.5470343647, 8.960299187787};
Point(183) = {162.83, 112.0063668288, -11.81189049095};
Point(184) = {162.83, 112.8580886594, -7.563638747806};
Point(185) = {162.83, 113.7911924628, -3.327492330721};
Point(186) = {162.83, 114.8051634714, 0.8934863723831};
Point(187) = {162.83, 115.9752992759, 5.373959934968};
Point(188) = {162.83, 116.5470343647, 8.960299187787};
Point(189) = {166.04, 112.0063668288, -11.81189049095};
Point(190) = {166.04, 112.8580886594, -7.563638747806};
Point(191) = {166.04, 113.7911924628, -3.327492330721};
Point(192) = {166.04, 114.8051634714, 0.8934863723831};
Point(193) = {166.04, 115.9752992759, 5.373959934968};
Point(194) = {166.04, 116.5470343647, 8.960299187787};
Point(195) = {169.25, 112.0063668288, -11.81189049095};
Point(196) = {169.25, 112.8580886594, -7.563638747806};
Point(197) = {169.25, 113.7911924628, -3.327492330721};
Point(198) = {169.25, 114.8051634714, 0.8934863723831};
Point(199) = {169.25, 115.9752992759, 5.373959934968};
Point(200) = {169.25, 116.5470343647, 8.960299187787};
Point(201) = {172.46, 112.0063668288, -11.81189049095};
Point(202) = {172.46, 112.8580886594, -7.563638747806};
Point(203) = {172.46, 113.7911924628, -3.327492330721};
Point(204) = {172.46, 114.8051634714, 0.8934863723831};
Point(205) = {172.46, 115.9752992759, 5.373959934968};
Point(206) = {172.46, 116.5470343647, 8.960299187787};
Point(207) = {175.67, 112.0063668288, -11.81189049095};
Point(208) = {175.67, 112.8580886594, -7.563638747806};
Point(209) = {175.67, 113.7911924628, -3.327492330721};
Point(210) = {175.67, 114.8051634714, 0.8934863723831};
Point(211) = {175.67, 115.9752992759, 5.373959934968};
Point(212) = {175.67, 116.5470343647, 8.960299187787};
Point(332) = {143.57, 116.9603952608, -59.69004406268};
Point(333) = {143.57, 116.4134726069, -55.84220806135};
Point(334) = {143.57, 115.3388896447, -51.37912417541};
Point(335) = {143.57, 114.3355740901, -46.89960607426};
Point(336) = {143.57, 113.4130234166, -42.40438452175};
Point(337) = {143.57, 112.5717726812, -37.89651842612};
Point(338) = {143.57, 111.8122411297, -33.37908470765};
Point(339) = {146.78, 116.9603952608, -59.69004406268};
Point(340) = {146.78, 116.4134726069, -55.84220806135};
Point(341) = {146.78, 115.3388896447, -51.37912417541};
Point(342) = {146.78, 114.3355740901, -46.89960607426};
Point(343) = {146.78, 113.4130234166, -42.40438452175};
Point(344) = {146.78, 112.5717726812, -37.89651842612};
Point(345) = {146.78, 111.8122411297, -33.37908470765};
Point(346) = {149.99, 116.9603952608, -59.69004406268};
Point(347) = {149.99, 116.4134726069, -55.84220806135};
Point(348) = {149.99, 115.3388896447, -51.37912417541};
Point(349) = {149.99, 114.3355740901, -46.89960607426};
Point(350) = {149.99, 113.4130234166, -42.40438452175};
Point(351) = {149.99, 112.5717726812, -37.89651842612};
Point(352) = {149.99, 111.8122411297, -33.37908470765};
Point(353) = {153.2, 116.9603952608, -59.69004406268};
Point(354) = {153.2, 116.4134726069, -55.84220806135};
Point(355) = {153.2, 115.3388896447, -51.37912417541};
Point(356) = {153.2, 114.3355740901, -46.89960607426};
Point(357) = {153.2, 113.4130234166, -42.40438452175};
Point(358) = {153.2, 112.5717726812, -37.89651842612};
Point(359) = {153.2, 111.8122411297, -33.37908470765};
Point(360) = {156.41, 116.9603952608, -59.69004406268};
Point(361) = {156.41, 116.4134726069, -55.84220806135};
Point(362) = {156.41, 115.3388896447, -51.37912417541};
Point(363) = {156.41, 114.3355740901, -46.89960607426};
Point(364) = {156.41, 113.4130234166, -42.40438452175};
Point(365) = {156.41, 112.5717726812, -37.89651842612};
Point(366) = {156.41, 111.8122411297, -33.37908470765};
Point(367) = {159.62, 116.9603952608, -59.69004406268};
Point(368) = {159.62, 116.4134726069, -55.84220806135};
Point(369) = {159.62, 115.3388896447, -51.37912417541};
Point(370) = {159.62, 114.3355740901, -46.89960607426};
Point(371) = {159.62, 113.4130234166, -42.40438452175};
Point(372) = {159.62, 112.5717726812, -37.89651842612};
Point(373) = {159.62, 111.8122411297, -33.37908470765};
Point(374) = {162.83, 116.9603952608, -59.69004406268};
Point(375) = {162.83, 116.4134726069, -55.84220806135};
Point(376) = {162.83, 115.3388896447, -51.37912417541};
Point(377) = {162.83, 114.3355740901, -46.89960607426};
Point(378) = {162.83, 113.4130234166, -42.40438452175};
Point(379) = {162.83, 112.5717726812, -37.89651842612};
Point(380) = {162.83, 111.8122411297, -33.37908470765};
Point(381) = {166.04, 116.9603952608, -59.69004406268};
Point(382) = {166.04, 116.4134726069, -55.84220806135};
Point(383) = {166.04, 115.3388896447, -51.37912417541};
Point(384) = {166.04, 114.3355740901, -46.89960607426};
Point(385) = {166.04, 113.4130234166, -42.40438452175};
Point(386) = {166.04, 112.5717726812, -37.89651842612};
Point(387) = {166.04, 111.8122411297, -33.37908470765};
Point(388) = {169.25, 116.9603952608, -59.69004406268};
Point(389) = {169.25, 116.4134726069, -55.84220806135};
Point(390) = {169.25, 115.3388896447, -51.37912417541};
Point(391) = {169.25, 114.3355740901, -46.89960607426};
Point(392) = {169.25, 113.4130234166, -42.40438452175};
Point(393) = {169.25, 112.5717726812, -37.89651842612};
Point(394) = {169.25, 111.8122411297, -33.37908470765};
Point(395) = {172.46, 116.9603952608, -59.69004406268};
Point(396) = {172.46, 116.4134726069, -55.84220806135};
Point(397) = {172.46, 115.3388896447, -51.37912417541};
Point(398) = {172.46, 114.3355740901, -46.89960607426};
Point(399) = {172.46, 113.4130234166, -42.40438452175};
Point(400) = {172.46, 112.5717726812, -37.89651842612};
Point(401) = {172.46, 111.8122411297, -33.37908470765};
Point(402) = {175.67, 116.9603952608, -59.69004406268};
Point(403) = {175.67, 116.4134726069, -55.84220806135};
Point(404) = {175.67, 115.3388896447, -51.37912417541};
Point(405) = {175.67, 114.3355740901, -46.89960607426};
Point(406) = {175.67, 113.4130234166, -42.40438452175};
Point(407) = {175.67, 112.5717726812, -37.89651842612};
Point(408) = {175.67, 111.8122411297, -33.37908470765};
Point(409) = {179.394615, 116.9603952608, -59.69004406268};
Point(410) = {179.394615, 116.4134726069, -55.84220806135};
Point(411) = {179.394615, 115.3388896447, -51.37912417541};
Point(412) = {179.394615, 114.3355740901, -46.89960607426};
Point(413) = {179.394615, 113.4130234166, -42.40438452175};
Point(414) = {179.394615, 112.5717726812, -37.89651842612};
Point(415) = {179.394615, 111.8122411297, -33.37908470765};
Point(416) = {179.394615, 111.1347315991, -28.85517391567};
Point(417) = {179.394615, 111.0863688623, -24.59240963891};
Point(418) = {179.394615, 111.1202830363, -20.32937265135};
Point(419) = {179.394615, 111.2364258104, -16.06916792827};
Point(420) = {179.394615, 112.0063668288, -11.81189049095};
Point(421) = {179.394615, 112.8580886594, -7.563638747806};
Point(422) = {179.394615, 113.7911924629, -3.327492330721};
Point(423) = {179.394615, 114.8051634714, 0.8934863723831};
Point(424) = {179.394615, 115.975299276, 5.373959934968};
Point(425) = {179.394615, 116.5470343647, 8.960299187787};
Point(426) = {187.6123075, 111.2364258104, -16.06916792827};
Point(427) = {187.6123075, 112.0063668288, -11.81189049095};
Point(428) = {187.6123075, 112.8580886594, -7.563638747806};
Point(429) = {187.6123075, 113.7911924628, -3.327492330721};
Point(430) = {187.6123075, 114.8051634714, 0.8934863723831};
Point(431) = {187.6123075, 115.9752992759, 5.373959934968};
Point(432) = {187.6123075, 116.5470343647, 8.960299187787};
Point(440) = {187.6123075, 111.1347315991, -28.85517391567};
Point(441) = {187.6123075, 111.0863688623, -24.59240963891};
Point(442) = {187.6123075, 111.1202830363, -20.32937265135};
Point(446) = {187.6123075, 116.9603952608, -59.69004406268};
Point(447) = {187.6123075, 116.4134726069, -55.84220806135};
Point(448) = {187.6123075, 115.3388896447, -51.37912417541};
Point(449) = {187.6123075, 114.3355740901, -46.89960607426};
Point(450) = {187.6123075, 113.4130234166, -42.40438452175};
Point(451) = {187.6123075, 112.5717726812, -37.89651842612};
Point(452) = {187.6123075, 111.8122411297, -33.37908470765};
Point(477) = {143.57, 117.3928571429, -63.31000004655};
Point(478) = {146.5238230769, 117.3928571429, -63.31000002907};
Point(479) = {149.99, 117.3928571429, -63.31000004655};
Point(480) = {154.7415192307, 117.3928571429, -63.31000002657};
Point(481) = {156.41, 117.3928571429, -63.31000004655};
Point(482) = {159.62, 117.3928571429, -63.31000004655};
Point(483) = {162.9592153846, 117.3928571429, -63.31000002408};
Point(484) = {166.04, 117.3928571429, -63.31000004655};
Point(485) = {169.25, 117.3928571429, -63.31000004655};
Point(486) = {171.1769115384, 117.3928571429, -63.31000002158};
Point(487) = {175.67, 117.3928571429, -63.31000004655};
Point(488) = {179.3946153846, 117.3928571429, -63.30999999162};
Point(489) = {187.6123076923, 117.3928571429, -63.30999998662};

Line(1) = {1, 2};
Line(2) = {2, 3};
Line(3) = {3, 4};
Line(4) = {4, 147};
Line(5) = {147, 148};
Line(6) = {148, 149};
Line(7) = {149, 150};
Line(8) = {150, 151};
Line(9) = {151, 152};
Line(10) = {152, 158};
Line(11) = {158, 164 };
Line(12) = {164,170 };
Line(13) = {170,176 };
Line(14) = {176,175 };
Line(15) = {175,174 };
Line(16) = {174,173 };
Line(17) = {173, 172};
Line(18) = {172, 171};
Line(19) = {171, 20};
Line(21) = {20, 19};
Line(22) = {19, 18};
Line(23) = {18, 17};
Line(24) = {17, 13};
Line(25) = {13, 9};
Line(26) = {9, 5};
Line(27) = {5, 1};


Curve Loop(1) = {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
Surface(1) = {1};

Point{169,168,167,166,165,16,15,14,163,157,162,156,
161,155,160,154,159,153,12,8,11,7,10,6} In Surface {1};



